# SAPUI5 SmartField not in Edit Mode

Tags: sapui5

Does anyone know why I might be having trouble getting my SmartField to render in edit mode? No matter what I do, it seems to insist on being display-only. My field is bound to a property from an oData model, which has an actual SAP oData service as its data source. I do indeed have the sap:updatable attribute equal to true in the metadata for my Property. I accomplished this by setting the property's "updatable" checkbox in the EDM in SEGW.

I run my application on FLP + service /sap/bc/lrp is activated.
SAPUI5 version : 1.52.16

Any thoughts?

The solution = 
The EntitySet has to be Updatable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. EntitySet itself must have the property updatable = true